# IsoDep and Android NFC - Payment Card not detected

Tags: android, nfc, apdu

I'm working on a payment application and the global idea is to convert the smartphone into a POS (Mobile POS)

I've searched a lot on the web (and here too !), I found answers to a part of all my questions but it remains one problem.

Everything seems to be correct, but the card isn't detected by the smartphone...

Here is my Manifest.xml (important parts...)

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"/>

<use-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

<meta-data 
    android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android.resource="@xml/nfc_tech_list"/>
```

In my nfc_tech_list.xml I put IsoDep, NfcA and NfcB.

For the moment, I just have one activity. Here's the code :

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

private final byte[] SELECT_PPSE = {
        (byte) 0x00, // CLA
        (byte) 0xA4, // INS
        (byte) 0x04, // P1
        (byte) 0x00, // P2
        (byte) 0x0E, // Lc
        0x32, 0x50, 0x41, 0x59, 0x2E, 0x53, 0x59, 0x53, 0x2E, 0x44, 0x44, 0x46, 0x20, 0x31,
        (byte) 0x00
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setting the Action Bar
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // Checking if the NFC is enabled
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled())
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Veuillez activer le NFC dans vos paramètres", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // Is the intent for a new NFC Tag Discovery
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);

        if (isoDep == null)
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Bon début", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Mauvais début", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0,
                    new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0),
            new IntentFilter[]{new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)},
            new String[][]{new String[]{IsoDep.class.getName()}}
    );
```

The problem is that the card isn't detected at all whereas other tags are...

Can anybody help me ?

EDIT : I'm working with a Galaxy Note 3 Lite

EDIT 2 : Here's my techlist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resource xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post your tech list, maybe? You might be unintentionally excluding the card from your filter. What tech(s) do you expect the card to match on?

EDIT:
Try this:

```
<tech-list>
  <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
  <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
  <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
  <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
  <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
</tech-list>
```

Comment: I'm working on Mastercards, so according to ISO 14443, the tech I'm expecting are NfcA and NfcB.

Comment: You want the differing techs you need to catch to be defined in _separate_ lists, whilst techs defined within the same list will be logically ANDed, meaning your card must fulfill all of them for the intent to get passed.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot. I suspect my contactless card not working properly, so I'll wait tomorow for having a new one and test it.

Comment: I tried another card with the different tech list but nothing happens :(
Normaly, when you scan a Tag with Android, even it's not supported the smartphone toast you that it's not compatible but nothing...

Comment: I found the solution ! (finally)
My phone doesn't support a lot of NFC tag technology, I tried your solution with a diffrent smartphone (Galaxy SIII) and it works :)